# .htaccess Rewrite: how to ignore sub pages

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have WordPress pages like

https://example.com/mainpage

https://example.com/mainpage/sub-page1

https://example.com/mainpage/sub-page2

https://example.com/mainpage/sub-page3

I have written a RewriteRule just for mainpage

`RewriteRule ^mainpage$ mainpage.php [L,QSA]`

also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainpage/sub-page1
RewriteRule ^mainpage$ mainpage.php [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainpage/.*$
RewriteRule ^mainpage$ mainpage.php [L,QSA]
```

but all the sub-pages also end up in mainpage.php instead of loading the WordPress pages.
How can I stop subpages loading mainpage.php

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Why would you need to rewrite any WP page to a custom script file in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My page was https://example.com/mainpage.

1. I changed the filename to "main_page.php" instead of mainpage.php
2. Added the rewiterule  `RewriteRule ^mainpage$ main_page.php [L,QSA]`

These changes worked for me.

Comment: The question was about mod_rewrite with Wordpress.
It's completly pointless share your experience if it's not about the same technology

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` from the pattern, and add `/` and write it like this `RewriteRule ^mainpage/ mainpage.php [L,QSA]`

Hopefully, this should ignore sub-pages.

Comment: i tried your solution but did not work